# RESCO OfflineHtml: Unable to Debug the Javascript code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-debugging, javascript-debugger

I am unable to debug the Javascript code in RESCO. I followed the given link - https://docs.resco.net/wiki/Debugging_offline_HTML

Steps Followed -

1. Wrote the code in Visual Studio and placed debugger; at the first line.

[image]

2. Attached To Process "MobileCrm.exe"

[image]

3. Enabled debugging in Internet Explorer -

[image]

4. Opened the RESCO App -> Opened the Form where the html is placed..but still it does not go into Visual Studio for debugging.

Kindly provide suggestions if i have missed any step.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: First, try to reset all vs settings by `Tools`--> `Import and Export Settings`-->`Reset All Settings`. You can also make a backup about your settings.  Besides, try to disable option `Enable Just My Code` under `Tools`-->`Options`-->`Debugging`-->`General`.

Comment: When you attach your app in VS, open the html form and then you should click on the UI option to hit the breakpoint.